# Ajax CORS + Basic Authorization

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http, cross-domain

Подкипает мозг.
Делаю кроссдомен POST с Basic Authorization.

Естественно отправляется предполётный `OPTIONS` на который возвращается `"The response had HTTP status code 403."` вместе с `"No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."`. Значит ли что при отсутствии базовой авторизации сервер не отдаёт разрешающие заголовки для кроссдоменых запросов?

```
ajaxSettings = {
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("user:pass"));
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
    },
    url: 'https://someurl/api',
    method: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {},
    global: true,
    async: true,
    error: function (request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        _log('API ERROR: ', arguments);
    },
    success: function(data) {

    }
};

$.ajax(ajaxSettings);
```

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://someurl/api. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.`

Comment: Это вопрос к серверу, попробуйте ручками (курлом например) поотправлять запросы и проверить наличие нужных заголовков

Comment: @Darth К серверу лично я доступа не имею. Сказали, что с OPTIONS не приходит авторизация. `OPTIONS /api/ HTTP/1.0`. Открываю адрес в браузере - заголовки `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` - есть.  В кроссдоменке их я не вижу.

Comment: Кто такая кроссдоменка? Откройте консоль и напишите там `curl -X OPTIONS https://someurl/api -v`, и посмотрите есть там CORS заголовки или нет. Если нет - пишите тому, у кого есть доступ к серверу, либо организуйте прокси который будет эти заголовки докидывать

Comment: @Darth, разобрался, спасибо за помощь

Comment: @AlexeyLemesh как решили вопрос? Судя по заголовкам - не разрешено делать запрос с локалхоста. А если присылать с сервера заголовок  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '*', то это так же не будет работать, т.к. basic авторизация недопустима при таком заголовке